# How do you make "background: url("") (CSS) a customizable image in wordpress for a client

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have this in my style.css

```
.showcase{

   background: url("x.jpg") no-repeat 0;

}
```

I have the website on wordpress. And i have advanced custom fields so that the client can change text on the website. But I can't seem to figure out how to do it for this CSS backround image.

The "additional CSS" part in WordPress doesn't work as it wants my style.css to be placed above bootstrap in index.php which causes a mess in itself. And it is also unfriendly towards non-developers, which is the part I cannot go forward with.

Please keep in mind that I have no experience using WordPress and am only converting a html static website to a WordPress one with some customisation enabled for the client. All of it is done except the images.

Comment: Do you use a Wordpress theme? Do you want to / Can you write some php code?

Answer (score 0):

upload the image in the gallery, get the absolute URL of the image

```css
.backgroundImage {
  height:500px;
  background-image: url("https://c1.staticflickr.com/9/8294/7597202086_aa54c17b83_b.jpg");
}
```

```html
<div class="backgroundImage">Background Image</div>
```

Comment: The correct answer would be using [`add_action('wp_head',...`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_head) (the first example) in the functions.php file to put ACF field as  background image.